# How to display data from firebase in a loop

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have data in firebase, I would like to display them using a loop.

```
    items: any;

    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        db.list(`/users/`).snapshotChanges()
            .subscribe(o => { this.items = o; console.log(o) });
    }

    <div *ngFor="let item of items;">
        Items: {{item.key}}
        <p *ngFor="let device of item;">{{device.name}}</p>
    </div>
```

I can't display the second loop, NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. How to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

In firebase, retrieving data via snapshotChanges() includes metadata with actual data in form of {key, payload, prevKey, type}.

In user case, you are trying to access **item.name**, but it is undefined.

You have to extract the payload before iterating. You can try something like this.

```
items$: any;

    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.items$ = db.list(`/users/`).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(map(changes => changes.map(c => ({
                key: c.key,
                payload: c.payload.val(),
                type: c.type,
                prevKey: c.prevKey
            }))));
    }

    <div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async;">
        Items: {{item.key}}
        name: {{item.payload.name}}
    </div>
```

If you don't need **key**, use valueChanges() instead of snapshotChanges().

For more details https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md